# Toggle target values of function call

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following function below which does a xmlhttprequest based in two targets which i get from the text of certain html elements.

All I need to do is switch the target values around, but without calling them each time in the if statement. Trying to follow the DRY method.

See below -

```
   if(whichSym === "1"){
      document.getElementById('priceSym' + whichSym).innerHTML = target;
      target2 = document.getElementById('priceSym2').innerHTML;
      dataControl.getItem(function(err, data) {
        uiControl.changeInput("1", data);
      }, target, target2);
    }
    else if(whichSym === "2"){
      document.getElementById('priceSym' + whichSym).innerHTML = target;
      target2 = document.getElementById('priceSym1').innerHTML;
      dataControl.getItem(function(err, data) {
        uiControl.changeInput("1", data);
      }, target2, target);
    }
```

Please let me know if you need more context.

Comment: can whichSym be just 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes, that's the only 2 options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow the DRY principle you can simply wrap it in a function. Something like this should work:

```
function (whichSym) {
    const otherSym = whichSym === 1 ? 2 : 1; // assuming values can be only 1 and 2
    const target = document.getElementById('priceSym' + whichSym).innerHTML;
    const target2 = document.getElementById('priceSym' + otherSym).innerHTML;
    dataControl.getItem((err, data) => {
        uiControl.changeInput("1", data); // not sure what "1" here means, replace with whichSym if needed
    }, target, target2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help

Comment: Great! Good luck to you!